# How To Transfer Data From One Promoted Widget Form To Another

Tags: c++, qt

I have an app with a MainWindow form and it consists of two promoted QWidget forms. My Output form QComboBox cannot access data from the Input form QLineEdit without crashing the app. I would  just like to have the MainWindow form load and have the MainWindow's Input form QLineEdit send data to the MainWindow's Output form QComboBox.

1. I tried a getter function that emits the QLineEdit data via a signal. I created a setter function in the Output class to receive the data. I created an instance of the Input class in the Output class and connected them in the OutputForm.cpp. The problem is I have to show the instance of the Input class which causes two forms to appear; the MainWindow form and a separate Input form.
2. I tried to access the Input form's ui in the OutputForm.cpp by adding the InputForm class to the OutputForm's Ui Namespace and creating an instance of the Inputput form ui in the OutputForm class. But, when I try to access the InputForm's QLineEdit data from the OutputForm's setter function, the app crashes.

code from #2:

```
//mainwindow.h
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>


QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H

//mainwindow.cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "./ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

```
//inputform.h
#ifndef INPUTFORM_H
#define INPUTFORM_H

#include <QPushButton>
#include <QWidget>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui {
class InputForm;
}
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class InputForm : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

    friend class OutputForm;

public:
    explicit InputForm(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~InputForm();

private:
    Ui::InputForm *ui;
    QString input_file{};

private Q_SLOTS:
    void select_input();

Q_SIGNALS:
    void new_line_edit_data(const QString &text);

};

#endif // INPUTFORM_H
```

```
//inputform.cpp
#include <QFileDialog>

#include "inputform.h"
#include "ui_inputform.h"

InputForm::InputForm(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::InputForm)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    connect(ui->inputPushButton, &QPushButton::clicked,
            this, &InputForm::select_input);
}

InputForm::~InputForm()
{
    delete ui;
}

void InputForm::select_input()
{
    this->input_file =
            QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(
                this,
                tr("Open File"),
                "C:/input_file");
    if(!this->input_file.isEmpty())
    {
        ui->inputLineEdit->setText(this->input_file);
    }
}
```

```
//outputform.h
#ifndef OUTPUTFORM_H
#define OUTPUTFORM_H

#include <QWidget>

#include "inputform.h"


QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui {
class OutputForm;
class InputForm;
}
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class OutputForm : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit OutputForm(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~OutputForm();

private:
    Ui::OutputForm *ui;
    Ui::InputForm *iui;
    QString input_text{};
    QStringList outputExtenionList{};


public Q_SLOTS:
    void select_container();

};

#endif // OUTPUTFORM_H
```

```
//outputform.cpp
#include "outputform.h"
#include "ui_outputform.h"
#include "ui_inputform.h"

#include <QFile>


OutputForm::OutputForm(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::OutputForm),
    iui(new Ui::InputForm)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    connect(ui->outputComboBox, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)),
            this, SLOT(select_container()));

    ui->outputComboBox->insertItem(0, "Source");
    ui->outputComboBox->insertSeparator(1);
    outputExtenionList << ".mp4" << ".mkv";
    ui->outputComboBox->insertItems(2, outputExtenionList);
}

OutputForm::~OutputForm()
{
    delete ui;
}

void OutputForm::select_container()
{
    QString source_ext{};
    QString line_edit_text{};
     line_edit_text = iui->inputLineEdit->text();

    if(ui->outputComboBox->currentIndex() == 0)
    {
        //copy source file extension
        //experiemntal
        QString input_file1_str{line_edit_text};

        source_ext = input_file1_str.mid(input_file1_str.lastIndexOf("."));
        ui->outputComboBox->currentText() = source_ext;
        ui->outputLabel->setText(source_ext);
    }
    if(ui->outputComboBox->currentIndex() == 2)
    {
        //mp4
        source_ext = ".mp4";
        ui->outputLabel->setText(source_ext);
    }
    if(ui->outputComboBox->currentIndex() == 3)
    {
        //mkv
        source_ext = ".mkv";
        ui->outputLabel->setText(source_ext);
    }
}
```

Comment: It probably isn't the cause of your crash, but this line is definitely wrong:  `ui->outputComboBox->currentText() = source_ext;` ... I think you want something more like `ui->outputComboBox->setCurrentText(source_ext);`

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: Jeremy, thank you for responding, and your help. I corrected my code with your suggestion but it still crashes.

Comment: If I disable ...line_edit_text = iui->inputLineEdit->text();... or set line_edit_text to some other string, it doesn't crash. Is line_edit_text = iui->inputLineEdit->text() the correct process when I'm trying to grab text directly from a QLineEdit in another form?

Comment: First thing you should do is determine exactly which line of code causes the crash.  You can do that using a debugger, or by sprinkling temporary `printf()` statements (or `qDebug()` or `cout << "blah" << endl;` or whatever you prefer) around the program to see which ones get printed out before the crash and which ones do not.  Once you know the line where the crash occurs, you'll have good info about why the crash occurs -- most likely that line is trying to dereference a bad pointer (via `->`).

Comment: On the line before the crashing you can print out the values of any pointers dereferenced in the crashing line (e.g. `printf("iui=%p\n", iui);`) to see if they look valid or not.  If any of them are printed out as `0x0` or some other suspiciously small number, that is probably the bad pointer, and you can move on to figuring out *why* it is not pointing to a valid memory location.

Comment: I ran 'printf("iui=%p\n", iui);' and I got 'iui=0xe34900'

Comment: `0xe34900` does seem suspiciously small to me... I recommend finding the place where that pointer is set/initialized, and printing out its value just after that, to see if it is the same there (and if the initialization is actually being executed!)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: I wanted to report this as solved. I resolved both of my issues by making my form to form connection in the MainWindow.cpp: `connect(ui->InputWidget, SIGNAL(new_line_edit_data(QString)),
            ui->OutputWidget, SLOT(receive_line_edit_data(QString)));`